# Retrieving error when reading a .npy file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to read a large .npy file but I am unable to read the file. Below is my python code for reading the file.

```
import numpy as np

pre_train = np.load('weights.npy',allow_pickle=True, encoding="latin1")
data_pic = pre_train.item()
#print(type(data_dic))
for item in data_pic:
    print(item)
```

Error at: `data_pic = pre_train.item()`

```
Can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Comment: At which exact line is the error raised? Did you save the data using pickle? Is it possible to have a sample of your data, Just to see what it looks like? (if data is sensitive, don't share ;) )

Comment: I havent saved the file I downloaded the dataset online. The error is raised on data.item line. Thanks @FlorianFasmeyer

Comment: The error occurs after the `load`.  So  you are able to read it!  What's the purpose of the `item()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not crash when loading the file. It crashes when using [numpy.ndarray.item](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.item.html). In your case, you do not need to use `item()`.

Using a good old for-loop will do!

```
data = np.load('...')
for i in data:
    for j in i:
        print(j)

# 2, 2, 6, 1, ...
```